# Problem with in-degrees in Kahn's algorithm implementation in c

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, topological-sort

I am trying to make a serial code for Kahn's Algorithm in C. The pseudocode I based it on is the following:

```
S ← Set of all nodes with no incoming edge 

while S is non-empty do     
    remove a node n from S     
    add n to tail of L
    for each node m with an edge e from n to m do
         remove edge e from the graph
         if m has no other incoming edges then
             insert m into S 

if graph has edges then
    return error   (graph has at least one cycle) 
else      
    return L       (a topologically sorted order)
```

My code reads a .mtx file that shows the adjacency of the nodes in the graph and it is this one:

```
7 11
7 8
3 8
11 2
11 9
11 10
8 9
3 10
```

I use an int array called **indegree** that holds the in-degrees for each node i. For example if node 5 has an in-degree value of 3 then: indegree[5]=3. The value indegree[i] is incremented by one whenever i is read as the second number in each line in the file. That signifies that there is an edge pointing to node i. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//struct for queues L and S
struct Queue
{
    int front, rear, size;
    unsigned capacity;
    int* array;
};

struct Queue* createQueue(unsigned capacity)
{
    struct Queue* queue = (struct Queue*) malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    queue->capacity = capacity;
    queue->front = queue->size = 0;  
    queue->rear = capacity - 1;  
    queue->array = (int*) malloc(queue->capacity * sizeof(int));
    return queue;
}

int isFull(struct Queue* queue)
{  return (queue->size == queue->capacity);  }

int isEmpty(struct Queue* queue)
{  return (queue->size == 0); }


//inserting element
void enqueue(struct Queue* queue, int item)
{
    if (isFull(queue))
        return;
    queue->rear = (queue->rear + 1)%queue->capacity;
    queue->array[queue->rear] = item;
    queue->size = queue->size + 1;
    printf("%d enqueued to queue\n", item);
}

//dequeueing element
int dequeue(struct Queue* queue)
{
    if (isEmpty(queue))
        return -1;
    int item = queue->array[queue->front];
    queue->front = (queue->front + 1)%queue->capacity;
    queue->size = queue->size - 1;
    return item;
}

//print queue
void print_queue(struct Queue* queue)
{
    int j;

    for(j=queue->front; j < queue->rear; j++)
{
printf("I put this number: %d in list L", queue->array[j]);
printf("\n");
}
}

int main()

{
FILE *fp; //filestream
int K,j,i,k;
int N=7;
char line[50];

fp = fopen("/home/konst/Documents/Project_Parallel/ibm32.mtx", "r");

//array that holds the in-degrees for each node i. For example if node 5 has an in-degree value of 3 then: indegree[5]=3
int indegree[N];

//when in .mtx file, it reads only the second number in each line, in this case i, and increases by one the value of indegree[i] (since there is an edge from node j to node i)
while(fgets(line,50,fp)!=NULL)  
    {  
sscanf(line, "%*d %d", &i);
printf("%d\n" , i);  //I inserted this print to check if the .mtx file is read correctly(it is!)
indegree[i] ++;
printf("Node : %d with indegree value: %d\n",i,indegree[i]);  //I inserted this print to check the indegree value that is incremented in each iteration 
    }


struct Queue* L = createQueue(N);  //N number of nodes
struct Queue* S = createQueue(N);  //N number of nodes

for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{

 if (indegree[i] == 0) //if this is true then node i doesnt have any incoming edges therefore I enqueue it in S
 {
printf("I found a value that has indegree[%d]=0 and put it in S queue\n", i);
enqueue(S, i);
 }

}

while (isEmpty(S) != 0) 
{
i = dequeue(S); 
enqueue(L,i);

while(fgets(line,50,fp)!=NULL)  
{  

sscanf(line, "%d%d",&j, &k); 
if (j == i)
{
indegree[k]--; 
break; 
}
}
if (indegree[k] == 0) 
enqueue(S,k);


}

if (isFull(L) !=0)
{
return -1; 
}
else
{
print_queue(L); 
}

fclose(fp);

}
```

**Now, the problem.** When I run my file (Compiler is gcc), the result I  get is this one:

```
11
Node : 12 with indegree value: -1
11
Node : 12 with indegree value: -1
8
Node : 8 with indegree value: 1
8
Node : 8 with indegree value: 2
2
Node : 2 with indegree value: 482383745
9
Node : 9 with indegree value: 1
10
Node : 10 with indegree value: -908997711
9
Node : 9 with indegree value: 2
10
Node : 10 with indegree value: -908997710
-1 enqueued to queue
-1 enqueued to queue
-1 enqueued to queue
-1 enqueued to queue
-1 enqueued to queue
-1 enqueued to queue
-1 enqueued to queue
```

Now first weird thing is that eventhough node 11 is read, node 12 is printed in the 'Node: x with indegree value: x' message. In some nodes these weird numbers keep getting printed as the values of indegree.. But for nodes 8 and 9 this works fine?!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, indent your code.

Secondly, you need to initalize the values of `indegree`. This is why some of the degrees you print are WAY off.

Thirdly, your `N` is too small. You set it to 7 but in the sample `.mtx` file you go all the way up to `11`. For that file you would need `N` to be 12.

Fourthly, if the output you provided is everything the program outputted then you aren't reading the `.mtx` file, since you print a line for each line you read.

Fifthly, why do you break the loop here:

```
if (j == i)
{
indegree[k]--; 
break; 
}
```

That would imply that you would never add more than one node to the queue at a time. Does that make sense?

Sixthly, you're implementation is lacking, to say the least.
You iterate through the adjacency list each iteration of the loop.
This gives us a worst case of `O(N^3)`, when Kahn's algorithm is actually linear.

Seventhly, I think the first line in the `.mtx` is separate from the rest.
I think it is saying that there are 7 egdes in the graph and 11 nodes.
You, however, treat it as the description of an edge.
If my assumption is correct, then this information can be used to dynamically determine `N`, instead of hardcoding it like you do.
You would then set `N` to be the second number on the first line.

Eigthly, you need to reset the filepointer.
So when you try to read the file again nothing will happen.
I also recommend not reading the file multiple times.
Rather store the values in an array.

Ninthly, it's nice to see you call `fclose` at the end, but if your graph includes a cycle then you return `-1` and don't call `fclose`.

**Regarding the comment below:**

To elucidate the fourth point, if this is everything your program outputs then

```
11
Node : 12 with indegree value: -1
11
Node : 12 with indegree value: -1
8
Node : 8 with indegree value: 1
8
Node : 8 with indegree value: 2
2
Node : 2 with indegree value: 482383745
9
Node : 9 with indegree value: 1
10
Node : 10 with indegree value: -908997711
9
Node : 9 with indegree value: 2
10
Node : 10 with indegree value: -908997710
-1 enqueued to queue
-1 enqueued to queue
-1 enqueued to queue
-1 enqueued to queue
-1 enqueued to queue
-1 enqueued to queue
-1 enqueued to queue
```

then this loop is never run:

```
while(fgets(line,50,fp)!=NULL)  
    {  
sscanf(line, "%*d %d", &i);
printf("%d\n" , i);  //I inserted this print to check if the .mtx file is read correctly(it is!)
indegree[i] ++;
printf("Node : %d with indegree value: %d\n",i,indegree[i]);  //I inserted this print to check the indegree value that is incremented in each iteration 
    }
```

I would simply initialize `indegree` with a for-loop.

As for `N`, you need it to be at least one larger than the name of the largest node in the input.
If some nodes don't appear in the file, like in the sample you gave, then they are still a part of your graph og shouldn't (generally) be ignored.
If you were implementing, for example, Dijkstra's graph search algorithm then you could ignore those nodes, but for Kahn you need to put them somewhere in your topological order (their location, however, is not important).
If you were to ignore isolated nodes you would have to do so carefully.
Doing it like you do leads to you pointing outside of `indegree`, since it has size 7 but some nodes are larger than that.
You would have to map their values down to 0, 1, ..., 6 to fit in the array.
This is not hard and can be done by sorting (log-linear time) or by using a hash-map (linear time).
To reitarate, this is not ideal in Kahn's algorithm because you need to account for the location of all the nodes in the topological order, so just put `N = 12` and ignore node `0`.
You can also set `N = 11` and decrement all the values in the `.mtx` file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! My .mtx file does not contain nodes 1,2,4,5. I am under the impression that N symbolizes the number of nodes in the graph. 
Should I still set the N to 12 if the previous nodes are not included? Secondly, I tried to initialize the indegree array with zeros (I assume that's what you mean?)
by writing indegree[n] = {0}, but I get an error. You are right about the first line of .mtx files usually stating the number of edges and nodes, however I have not included it in mine so that the file is read more effortlessly. Would you explain further your fourth point?